# Nginx captured regex can't be reused later for includes?

Tags: nginx, regex

I capture the server name like this:

```
server_name ~^(?<account>.+)\.myapp\.io$;
```

an later i try to use it on the same file, like:

```
include $account.conf;
```

but it returns:

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/$account.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

of course, the file exists.

If i use it somewhere else, it works, like:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/$account-access.log;
```

Comment: Not all directives accept variables. `include` is one of them.

Comment: `include` directive is processed only when nginx starts, and at startup, there is no request where the `server_name` could be parsed from.

What are you actually trying to accomplish?